# Fast solution to problems involving Lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ subject to the constraint $g(x_1,...,x_m)=0$ for some natural $m$. We can find the local maxima and minima of $f$ on $g$ by setting:

$F(x_1,...,\max (m,n),\lambda)=f(x_1,...,x_n)+\lambda g(x_1,...,x_m)=0$

Set all partial derivatives to zero and solve the system of equations. Now, suppose we have a solution and we want to find out whether it's a local maximum or minimum. I've searched and the only method to solve this that I've found is looking at the Hessian matrix for $F$. However, this process is very slow and in practical settings one usually gets a $3 \times 3$ or higher-dimensional matrix. Is there a faster method for finding whether a given solution is a maximum or minimum?

Comment: Evaluating the function in a small neighborhood of the given points may help you, generally speaking, yet it's not quite a 1:1 relation with the Hessian matrix

Comment: Plot it, perhaps?